# What is the most efficient way to concatenate thousands of dataframes in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I currently stored some data from a website that I have scraped into .csv for each product of the website. Since it is a quite popular website, I obtained more than 30,000 csv, that I need to merge into one. I'm not really an expert in pandas, but my first reaction was to rely on the concat() function. That is, my code looks like that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["product_id", "price"])
for file in onlyfiles:
    df1 = pd.read_csv(file)
    df = pd.concat([df, df1])
```

where onlyfiles represents the directory in which all my dataframes are stored. It works, but it is starting to slow down as the number of dataframes increases. However, it is obviously not the best efficient way to achieve this goal. Does anybody have an idea of a more efficient method to use here?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you perhaps merge the files into one before converting them into a dataframe? `cat *.csv > big.csv`

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48051100/python-pandas-merge-multiple-csv-files if it helps...

Comment: Maybe you need to merge all csv files into one big file, then remove extra rows with header and read it with pandas?

Comment: If all those files have the structure (product id and price) I'd merge them with `cat ./* > main.csv ` as Grizzle suggested.

Comment: @Grizzle I actually didn't think of cat! I'll try this right away, thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: @Leemosh They have indeed the same structure. Going to try cat, thank you for the idea!

Comment: I'll also suggest that concatenation should be done only after reading in all the files, so the concat part of your code should be moved out of the for loop. I do agree with previous comments to just `cat` it if you are working on a linux machine. You could even filter out and do some preprocessing in Unix before reading it into Pandas. Alternatively, SQLite is not bad in holding your data

Answer (score 1):

You need to start storing your data in an SQL database, CSV files are not databases.

You might want to look into Postgresql as SQLite may not have all of the features you need. You should be able to set up SQL code that dumps data into a single database from a CSV file. I have an automated process that pulls CSV data into a database, regularly.

You can interact with Postgres with the Psycopg2 library in python. Another thing you may want to consider is using Pandasql, which allows you to manipulate your Pandas data frames with SQL code. I always import Pandasql when working with Pandas dataframes.

Here is an example of my Postgres CSV file data import:

```
--Data Import Query
COPY stock_data(date, ticker, industry, open, high, low, close, adj_close, volume, dor)
FROM 'C:\Users\storageplace\Desktop\username\company_data\stock_data\stockdata.csv'
DELIMITER ','
CSV HEADER;
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'm actually still a beginner in Python, which I mainly use for a past-time project, but I'll look into SQL database very soon, since I'll surely need it at some point.